# Xamarin show one item from DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to show **one** item with a DataTemplate in my Xamarin app, what XAML control can I use?

In my case I am building a meetings app and I am trying to show the meeting's owner.
I tried using CollectionView (UserTemplate is a DataTemplate):

```
<CollectionView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Meeting.Owner}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}"/>
```

but this didn't show anything because CollectionView supports only a list of items (and it's really worked when i tried to use a list). 
What alternative can I use for a single item?

UserTemplate XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate">
    <Grid Padding="10"
          RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
          ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
               Source="{Binding IconURL}" 
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               HeightRequest="60" 
               WidthRequest="60" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" 
               Text="{Binding Name}" 
               FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1" 
               Text="{Binding age}"
               FontAttributes="Italic" 
               VerticalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why not consider having a List with just one element in your ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this may not be a perfect solution but maybe it will help you.

Instead of a Template, you could use a ContentView for displaying your Data.
the XML for that would look almost similar to your Template.

XAML:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:TestAppNew.Models"
             x:Class="TestAppNew.Views.UserView"
             x:Name="View">

    <Frame BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference View}, Path=User}" 
           x:DataType="models:User">
        <Grid Padding="10"
              RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
              ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto">

            <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                   Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   Text="{Binding age}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic" 
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
    public partial class UserView : ContentView
    {
        public User User
        {
            get => (User)GetValue(UserProperty);
            set => SetValue(UserProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty UserProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("User", typeof(User), typeof(UserView), new User());

        public UserView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Now you are able to use this View in your Code.

Single Items:

```xml
<views:UserView User="{Binding Meeting.Owner}" />
```

Or Multiple:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:UserView User="{Binding Owner}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Without doing further researches, I think you should be able to Wrap this View in an extra DataTemplate so, that you could still access the direct ItemTemplate Attribute of a ListView or CollectionView

Comment: The advantage of this answer, is that UserView can be used directly to show one view. AND it can easily be wrapped with `DataTemplate`, where a template is needed. So it covers both situations. As mentioned in Namo's last paragraph, you can easily make a separate `DataTemplate` definition elsewhere, I'll name it `UserDataTemplate`, so that you can simply do `<CollectionView ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}"/>`.

Comment: NOTE: `Xamarin.Forms.ContentView` inherits from `BindableObject`, which contains a definition for `OnPropertyChanged`. So you can remove `, INotifyPropertyChanged` and `#region INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In this simple case, its also possible to use a simpler `Create` definition: `public static readonly BindableProperty UserProperty = BindableProperty.Create("User", typeof(User), typeof(UserView), new User());`. I recommend keeping it simple, so that people new to Xamarin Forms are not overwhelmed.

Comment: Yeah, you are right with the INotifyPropertyChanged. I Had some issues when I tested this code yesterday and implemented it for testing. I Forgot to remove it, so good call

Answer (score 0):

Given a `Meeting`, that contains a property `User`, how can we display a `DataTemplate` of `Meeting.User`?

To use `CollectionView`, we need a `List<User>`. One solution is to create a ["Value Converter"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BindSubView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a single object, return a list containing just that object.
    /// </summary>
    public class OneItemListConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new List<object> { value };
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindSubView"
                 x:Class="BindSubView.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:OneItemListConverter x:Key="oneItemList" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Meeting.User, Converter={StaticResource oneItemList}}" HeightRequest="100">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I've shown an inline `DataTemplate`, but this can use a DataTemplate defined elsewhere:

```
<CollectionView ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource YourTemplateName}"/>
```

The above answer uses the definitions of `MainPageViewModel`, `Meeting`, and `User` seen below.

---

OR If the goal is to display the details of a property (User) on another property (Meeting), might not need a DataTemplate at all.

This is a different goal than the question asked; this shows how to refer to "nested" properties such as "Meeting.User.Name".

Consider these models:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BindSubView
{
    public class Meeting : BindableObject
    {
        public string Description { get; set; } = "Description of meeting";
        public User User { get; set; } = new User();
    }

    public class User : BindableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Test User";
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; } = "Test SomeProperty";
    }
}
```

`: BindableObject` is optional; it is for use (later in development) of the convenience method `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeProperty));`

And this view model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableObject
{
    public Meeting Meeting { get; set; } = new Meeting();
}
```

Two possible approaches.

-1. Refer directly to "nested" properties. E.g. `{Binding Meeting.User.Name}`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindSubView"
             x:Class="BindSubView.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Meeting.Description}"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Meeting.User.Name}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Meeting.User.SomeProperty}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

OR 2. Set a different "BindingContext" on parts of the XAML.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindSubView"
             x:Class="BindSubView.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <!-- "Meeting" refers to a Property on the enclosing BindingContext. Here it means "MainPageViewModel.Meeting". -->
    <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding Meeting}">
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        <!-- "User" refers to a Property on the enclosing BindingContext. Here it means "MainPageViewModel.Meeting.User". -->
        <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding User}">
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

These two XAML snippets behave identically. Both display:

```
Description of meeting

Test User

Test SomeProperty
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to use UserTemplate because I use it in diffrent parts of my app (for example when showing the meeting's members or the friends of a user).

Comment: @MaayanKestler - ok, that makes sense. I've added a solution that uses a DataTemplate. See first solution in this answer.

Comment: @MaayanKestler - Nemo's answer is also a good approach.